# how to convert a tuple in to a 2D matrix

Tags: arrays, matrix, tuples

I a have tuple a with the shape of (3,1) and I would like to construct a 2D matrix X with the dimension(3,2). After X is constructed, there is a need to multiply X'*X which is supposed to be in the shape of (2,2)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HePgd.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
thistuple = (1, 2, 3)
arr=np.ones(shape=(len(thistuple),2))

tuple_index=0
for i in range(0,len(arr)):
  for j in range(0,len(arr[0])):
    if(tuple_index>=len(thistuple)):
        break
    arr[i][j]=thistuple[tuple_index]
    tuple_index+=1

rez = arr.T
result = np.dot(rez,arr)
print(result)
```

The above code will work for an tuple of shape n*1 in python.